# Choosing the Right Op Amp for Photodetection

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, photodiode

I aim to use a silicon PIN photodiode to detect light emitted from a set of chemical reactions from a chamber. I am having trouble choosing an appropriate op amp to order to convert the photodiode's output current into voltage, and to amplify the signal.

Apart from requiring a transimpedance amplifier setup, CMOS architecture, surface mount, and a signal output in the range of 0-5V (0V at no light), how do I determine other op amp parameters such as slew rate, slew rate, GBP, output type, input offset voltage and input bias?

This is the data sheet for the photodiode I plan on using:
https://datasheet.octopart.com/SFH-2430-Z-Osram-Opto-datasheet-107659643.pdf

Comment: "CMOS architecture" is irrelevant; all you need is FET inputs. Though if your light input is small enough (your application reminds me of scintillator applications in particle physics), you may not be able to get satisfactory results with a normal photodiode; photomultipliers may be required.

Comment: What are your frequency/speed requirements?

Comment: You have choose a PD that is very high speed (30ns) yet low uA/uW sensitivity as a tradeoff.  Don’t you have any design specs for signal BW, gain required or input power?

Comment: The input power will be supplied from an Arduino Micro that is connected to a PC via USB. How can I figure out the signal BW and required gain?

Comment: From the expected rise time and signal level, still no specs?  You have not supplied any info on your experiment or expectations. Gain and BW are tradeoffs.

Comment: You might tell us more about light generation of your chemical reactions. Perhaps these are single photons as Hearth suggests, perhaps many photons in a short burst as in a violent reaction, perhaps longer, like a firefly, perhaps something like phosphorescence.

Comment: The final reaction that emits light is between Horseradish peroxidase (HRP) and Amplex Red. Amplex red acts as an electron donor for HRP and the resulting chemical formed is resorufin, which is a fluorescent compound. Resorufin has a fluorescence emission maxima of 563-587 nm

Comment: The rise time is 200 microseconds and signal level is 6 microamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bandwidth is determined by how much your application needs (or typically the ADC). If you need to sample at say 1kHz (because you are trying to detect a pulse or something like that) then the analog bandwidth would be 1kHz or lower (lower is better because the lower the bandwidth (usually lowered by filtering) the lower the noise.

Once you determine the bandwidth of the system, you can select the rail (typically 5V or 3.3V, the higher the better Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR)).

The input offset voltage is a small voltage that is errors in the opamp that is considered on the terminals, lower is better. To much input offset voltage can cause problems for large gains.

GBP or GBWP is the bandwidth at unity gain and needs to be much higher than your system bandwidth. It also depends on the gain you set. You can think of the opamp like a low pass filter, if the gain is set too high then you might have issues with the bandwidth of the opamp. At 500Hz it probably won't be an issue for most designs, if you have a gain that's higher than 10^5 or 10^6 I'd worry about it.

Input bias current needs to be much lower than that of the photodiode, get one in the pA or fA range